# Symfony2 + FOSUserBundle - Password sem encoder

Tags: php, symfony

Usando Symfony2 mais FOSUserBundle, estou querendo que o cadastro do usuário no banco não tenha nenhum codificador de senha.

Em `security.yml` foi colocado:

```
encoders: FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: plaintext
```

Porém, ao eu criar o usuário pelo console:

```
fos:user:create -- admin admin@admin.com admin
```

A senha no banco é criado da seguinte forma: `admin{salt...}`. 
Em resumo, ele cria com a senha `admin` como foi informado mais o salt entre chaves, por exemplo: `admin{e3adudjubsgsg88kgwg4w4oscw8os4c}`.

O que devo fazer para que nesse campo fique somente a senha em `plaintext` sem o salt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analizando o código do framework, vi que as chamadas de código estão assim:

Classe `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoder`:

```
public function encodePassword(UserInterface $user, $plainPassword)
{
    $encoder = $this->encoderFactory->getEncoder($user);

    return $encoder->encodePassword($plainPassword, $user->getSalt());
}
```

Classe `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\BasePasswordEncoder`:

```
public function encodePassword($raw, $salt)
{
    if ($this->isPasswordTooLong($raw)) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException('Invalid password.');
    }

    return $this->mergePasswordAndSalt($raw, $salt);
}
```

Classe `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\PlaintextPasswordEncoder`:

```
protected function mergePasswordAndSalt($password, $salt)
{
    if (empty($salt)) {
        return $password;
    }

    if (false !== strrpos($salt, '{') || false !== strrpos($salt, '}')) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Cannot use { or } in salt.');
    }

    return $password.'{'.$salt.'}';
}
```

Ou seja, concatena-se o salt com a senha porque existe um salt no cadastro do usuário. Limpe esse campo que a senha retornada será a própria senha.